# Cannot open database "gainpeace" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MALIK\ASPNET'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I'm using this for connection to SQL Server 2005 [Windows authentication]

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=MALIK\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=gainpeace;Integrated Security=SSPI"></add>
```

but it generates an error

> Cannot open database "gainpeace"
>   requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user
>   'MALIK\ASPNET'.

plz guide me how to resolved this issue ...!

Comment: can you post the connection string u are using

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "Windows Authentication" and you have not added the ASPNET service account to your database as a user.  Under your database server in SQL Server Management Studio, there is a Security node, and under that there is a "Logins" node.   Right-click on "Logins" and choose "New Login".  In the dialog that pops up, under "Login name", click the button to "Search" and find the ASPNET user (on computer MALIK).  Then click on "User Mappings" on the left and check the box next to your database.  Also check the box below for "db_owner" (or less) in order to give your user some privileges.